# Chrome content/footer white spaces bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, frontend

I am developing website and have a strange bug that appears only on Chrome. I have a latest Chrome version and as I googled it seems to be old bug on older versions of Chrome(v18 - v20). Basically what happens: browser loads page, but on the bottom of the screen I have white spaces/rectangles instead of content or footer. Once I hover it - the rest of the content is loaded. Any ideas, links or solutions would be great.

I tried to work with this around with setting height to auto, but this didn't help. Also tried to load page in incognito to make sure it is not caused by any of the extensions I use, but this as well had no affect in resolving the issue.

Another solution that I think of is to set interval to re-trigger CSS in some milliseconds the page is loaded, but this is not the best solution and there should definitely be some other, more optimal, way to solve this.

P.S.:
All other browsers work like a charm.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you add a link to your site, or add your code?

Comment: Try to reproduce this on http://jsfiddle.net and post your link here.

Comment: Hello, this was caused by this css:
body{
 .animation(fade-in 0.7s ease-out);
}

I removed the line/effect and now it works as it should, but still it would be nice to have it. Maybe some ideas on why animation causes content not to be drawn on the screen and what could be a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case issue was with fade-in animation set on whole content. As website owner decided to skip the animation to save time. No further digging was done.